# Is it correct to say, 'Be knowledgeable of', or 'Be knowledgeable about'?

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say, 'Be knowledgeable of' or 'Be knowledgeable about'?
(As in, 'Be knowledgeable of the menu'.)
(Staff must be knowledgeable of the menu).

Answer (score 0):

The Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary says:

'be knowledgeable about'

So do OAL, LAL (Longman Advanced Learners)

but 'of' does work fine in spoken English and I wouldn't mark it as an error.